# queue job all day and execute it at a specified time

Tags: testing, jenkins, queue, delay, jobs

Is there a plugin or can I somehow configure it, that a job (that is triggered by 3 other jobs) queues until a specified time and only then executes the whole queue?

Our case is this:

1. we have tests run for 3 branches
2. each of the 3 build jobs for those branches triggers the same smoke-test-job that runs immediately
3. each of the 3 build jobs for those branches triggers the same complete-test-job

points 1. and 2. work perfectly fine.

The complete-test-job should queue the tests all day long and just execute them in the evening or at night (starting from a defined time like 6 pm), so that the tests are run at night and during the day the job is silent.
It's no option to trigger the complete-test-job on a specified time with the newest version. we absolutely need the trigger of the upstream build-job (because of promotion plugin and we do not want to run already run versions again).

Answer (score 0):

That seems a rather strange request. Why queue a build if you don't want it now... And if you want a build later, then you shouldn't be triggering it now.

You can use [**Jenkins Exclusion plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusion-Plugin). Have your test jobs use a certain resource. Make another job whose task is to "hold" the resource during the day. While the resource is in use, the test jobs won't run.

Problem with this: you are going to kill your executors by having queued non-executing jobs, and there won't be free executors for other jobs.

Comment: we just want to run the job (complete-test) once a day. if there are 5 builds that trigger the job, we just need the last build of those 5. if the tests run all the time there are licenses blocked that should not be blocked (test-software) and in some cases the test of the last build is not finished in the morning.

Comment: In that case, you should look into "Quiet Period" for the test job. Set it to something like 4 hours. This way, after the first trigger, it will wait for 4 hours, if nothing happens during the 4 hours, it will actually build. If another project triggers the build within 4 hours, it will reset the counter and wait again. This way, if you have multiple triggers happening during the day, the last one being at 5pm, the job will execute at 5+4 9pm. You can ever set the quiet period to 8 hours, so no tests happen during the day, but at 5+8 = 1AM

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386352/1861362) sounds like a solution to your problem.